# Showing successor task names in MS Project

Tags: ms-project

I'm new to MS Project. I have a view where I want to get a list of successors for a list of tasks. I've added the Successors column and that gives me the list I want, but it's their unique IDs. Is there a way to get the same list but it's their task names instead of their unique IDs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the Task Form shown in the bottom pane, right-click on any part of the Task Form and select "Predecessors and Successors."  The list of task successor relationships will be shown on the right side of the form.